# Changing the tempo of a MIDI or WAV/MP3 file in FMOD

Tags: c++, midi, fmod, audio-processing

Is it possible to change the tempo of a MIDI or WAV/MP3 file using FMOD? I am using C++ alongside FMOD and cannot seem to find a function which will let me control the tempo of an audio file from variables received in the C part of the application. I am using audio that I have written myself, so I'm going to make the tempo of all tracks the same so I don't need to worry about using/writing a function to calculate the bpm of anything.

Comment: Those are night and day different tasks.  Please pick whether you want to manipulate MIDI, or manipulate audio.

Answer (score 3):

To change playback speed you can use Channel::setFrequency, however this will affect the pitch also. You can then use an FMOD Pitch Shifter DSP to correct the pitch difference. This will work for any sound type in FMOD.

For MIDI you could try Sound::setMusicSpeed, this will control the MIDI speed directly without needing to use the DSP.